# manipulate css not to influence all elements

Tags: css

This css thing is driving me crazy.

I have a form where I put the following css script:

```
input, select, textarea
{
    color: #082C6B;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

in that form I also put the following button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" class="myButtonText" Style="font-size: 22px; float: left; height: 30px; width: 100px;" OnClick="btnSend_Click" CausesValidation="true" Text="send" />
```

I also put the following css script:

```
.myButtonShape
{
    /* fallback */
    background-color: #082c6b;
    /*background: url('../images/gradient-strip.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;*/ /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#53e0ff), to(#081a40)); /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #53e0ff, #081a40); /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #53e0ff, #081a40); /* IE 10 */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #53e0ff, #081a40); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #53e0ff, #081a40);
    /*border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;*/
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

now, since `asp:button` is translated to `input`... then the button gets the color of the script which i intended for fields data.
How can I ensure that the button will get the script of the '.myButtonShape' class? any ideas?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `class` correctly on the `<asp:Button>`. Right now it's set to `myButtonText`, so of course the styles for `myButtonShape` aren't being applied to it.

Comment: jeez, emberrasing :-) there were good answers but of course this is my mistake not declaring the right class. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is your  present in a  whose class is set to myButtonShape? Assuming that it is, I think it should work. If it still doesn't, try to use the `!important` property in the above CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your input css target specific types of input rather than  all input like this:

```
input[type="text"], select, textarea
{
    color: #082C6B;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```